# AppleScript deployment conventions?

Tags: applescript, package-management

I haven't seen a package-management system for AppleScripts, but it seems like the foundations for one are present.

Given:

- Scripts (and folder) located in the `~/Library/Scripts/Applications` folder ARE NOT visible from OS X AppleScript menu.
- Scripts (and folders) locate in the `~/Library/Scripts/` folder ARE visible from OS X AppleScript menu.

Implications:

- 'Libraries' scripts (i.e. those referenced by `load script`) could be located in `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/<namespace>/` folder
- 'Controller' scripts (i.e. those that are run by users) could be located in `~/Library/Scripts/<namespace>/` folder
- An installation script could be used to compile the `.applescript` files, create directories, and other minutiae.
- Projects would be located on `Github` (or similar)
- All that would remain is a directory service

Questions:

- Is there an AppleScript package-management system (that I've missed)?
- In lieu of that, is what I've described a reasonable deployment convention?
- Are there any conventions for `<namespace>`? Java uses reverse domain name (e.g. com.foo.project)

Comment: Using `~/Library/Scripts/<namespace>/` would be problematic because that namespace would show up as the folder name in the AppleScripts menu.